# Update MKPointAnnotation object while dragging

Tags: ios, swift2, mapkit, swift3, mapkitannotation

I want to know how to update my `annotation` title while i am dragging it because all the `annotation` properties are `get` only.

Code I have try:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {

    switch (newState) {
    case .starting:
        //view.dragState = .dragging
        print("dragging.....")
    case .ending, .canceling:
        // view.dragState = .none
        let lat = view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude
        let long = view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
        print(" pin lat \(lat) long \(long)")

        //Error here - title is get only property
        view.annotation?.title = "New Location"

    default: break
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the drag method of `MKMapViewDelegate`, annotation is read only so you can use `didSelectAnnotationView` method of `MKMapViewDelegate` because before drag it will call `didSelectAnnotationView` method, for that declare one `selectedAnnotation` instance property of type `MKPointAnnotation`.

```
var selectedAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation?
```

Now use this property in `didSelectAnnotationView` method.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    selectedAnnotation = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation
}
```

Now to change the title use this annotation

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
    switch (newState) {
        case .starting:
            //view.dragState = .dragging
            print("dragging.....")
        case .ending, .canceling:
            // view.dragState = .none
            let lat = view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude
            let long = view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
            print(" pin lat \(lat) long \(long)")
            self. selectedAnnotation?.title = "New Location"
        default: break
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding:)